# Install centreon on centos7.9 raspberrypi

Tags: repository, centos7, centreon-api

How guys, can you help me I have problem with install centreon:
`#yum install centreon-base-config-centreon-engine centreon`
output

```
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
  base: mirror.vpsnet.com
  centos-kernel: mirror.vpsnet.com
  extras: mirror.vpsnet.com
  updates: centosh9.centos.org
http://yum.centreon.com/standard/3.4/el7/stable/armhfp/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below wiki article

https://wiki.centos.org/yum-errors

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please use https://bugs.centos.org/.


 One of the configured repositories failed (Centreon Entreprise Linux reposistory contains software to use with Centreon.),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=centreon-stable ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable centreon-stable
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=centreon-stable

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=centreon-stable.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from centreon-stable: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://yum.centreon.com/standard/3.4/el7/stable/armhfp/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
What i done is:
ls /etc/yum.repos.d/
nano /etc/yum.repos.d/centreon.repo #enabled=0

Where can i find package for "centreon-base-config-centreon-engine centreon"

Answer (score 0):

The Centreon version 3.4 is not supported anymore.
You should use an newer version.
Latest is the 21.04.

This version comes with a script that does all the install automatically.
It is described in the "Packages" tab of the Centreon download site: https://download.centreon.com/